# Curl API request much slower than Postman and .NET HTTP Client

Tags: php, performance, curl, php-curl

I am working with a 3rd party dev agency to build an app, for which they are using PHP. They are making a request to an external API using the PHP Curl library.

The problem is it seems significantly slower than when calling via Postman OR using .NET Http client. Could someone please help on this.

Curl library: 7.64.0
PHP version: 8.1

private function request(string $url, $data)
{

```
    // Remove new lines
    $fields = array();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $value = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "", $value);
        array_push($fields, $key . '=' . urlencode($value));
    }

    // API call to Tourplan
    $dataText = implode('&', $fields);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataText);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300); //timeout in seconds
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    unset($dataText);


    if (!is_bool($result) && !empty($result) && $result) {
        // Convert from text/xml to SimpleXMLElement and then to stdClass
        return json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($result, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA)));
    } else {
        $this->logfile($data['XML'], 'request'.$logNom);
        $this->logfile($result, 'response'.$logNom);
        $this->log_file(curlerror($ch), 'error'.$logNom);
    }

    return false;
}
```

**API Request via .NET Http client**
[image]

**Processing time within app monitoring network call (Curl request response takes up 99% of this time)**
[image]

**Log file from app**
[image]

**Log file from Curl request:**

```
Array
(
    [url] => ----------Redacted------
    [content_type] => text/xml;charset=UTF-8
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 268
    [request_size] => 189
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 2.362271
    [namelookup_time] => 0.000847
    [connect_time] => 0.273085
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.825333
    [size_upload] => 1489
    [size_download] => 57727
    [speed_download] => 24439
    [speed_upload] => 630
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => 1489
    [starttransfer_time] => 1.0992
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 0
    [local_ip] => 
    [local_port] => 0
    [http_version] => 2
    [protocol] => 2
    [ssl_verifyresult] => 0
    [scheme] => HTTPS
    [appconnect_time_us] => 825272
    [connect_time_us] => 273085
    [namelookup_time_us] => 847
    [pretransfer_time_us] => 825333
    [redirect_time_us] => 0
    [starttransfer_time_us] => 1099200
    [total_time_us] => 2362271
)
```

Comment: We can't see the equivalent postman or .net requests and you provided no timing data. Without context it's difficult to have a starting point for understanding the issue. Please provide more details.

Comment: Apologies - as I don't have access to the code or inner workings this is currently all I have.  The first two are from my own testing and calling the API .NET. The dev agency also confirm that they are able to make the request via Postman in their location quickly but do not see the same speed via the Curl request within the app.

Comment: Well the agency need to send you their .net code and an export of the postman config, so we can compare. And you need to provide timings for comparison. We don't know how slow/fast you're talking about, or what speed you'd consider acceptable. Also if you're not doing all these requests from the same machine or even the same network then the language/tool might be irrelevant anyway. It could be environment factors such as network speed or slower hardware. At the moment we don't have any clues at all though. Maybe get the agency to run your curl code from their test machine too

Comment: This shouldn't be the case but check the code snippet from Postman and compare with your curl request, may be there might be some differences

Comment: Ok thanks. I thought it might be something to do with a bug in Curl library or a missing option. The 3rd party API whitelist IP addresses so you wouldnt be able to test this yourself. I will ask the agency to run on their local machines, the staging server and to send me logs/timings from both. But for clarity they are all making the exact same request, to the same end point with the same XML (i.e via Postman, my own testing in .NET code and their Curl request within the app).

Comment: OK. But we can't verify any of those assertions, so we can't be sure it's correct. Until we have test results of each piece of code all run from the same device, and the code/config of each environment then we don't have a [mre] of the issue and we can't even begin to decide if we think the php code is a factor or not, or what might need to be changed. Sorry but that's the way it is. Otherwise, it's total guesswork.

Comment: Appreciate what you are saying. Thanks

This is all I could get for now from the agency: Call from Postman on devs machine: 1463ms 
484ms
457ms
678ms

. Logged time for curl request within app on devs machine:
2000ms
2543ms
2345ms

. I will try and get full logs of both but for now they are focussing on getting the app live. I also asked them to try and update a later version of Curl (as I believe this might be a regression issue that has been fixed) - but they are claiming version 7.80 or above is unstable. This is completely unfounded and I don't think is the case.

Comment: I have also updated the question to include a log file from the agency showing the trace of the Curl request. Hopefully this helps. The exact same call via Postman from theirs and my machine is consistently less than 1 second. If anyone can spot anything here that would speed up the curl performance would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an update on this. It turns out that upgrading to a later version of the curl library resolved this. This was catalysed by finding this issue on Github:

https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/10119

The dev agency tested a version of the API request on a server with curl 7.80 and it reduced the response time by more than 50%. Hope this helps anyone else experiencing this issue.

The times are now inline with our tests using .NET and HTTPClient.